# Get only direct element value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have the following for my menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('ul li').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><i class="font-icon"></i> Users
      <ul>
        <li>Overview</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see as a return I get:

```
<i class="font-icon"></i> Users
<ul>
   <li>Overview</li>
</ul>
```

Now the problem is that I'm only interested in: `<i class="font-icon"></i> Users`. Is there a way to only get that as a return without putting it in a `div` or `span`? I already tried with `.text()` but this only gave me the actual text `Users` (obviously).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be the solution: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ejmdqLwm/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i=$('ul li').html();
    var ul=$('ul li').find('ul')[0].outerHTML;
    i=i.replace(ul,'');
    alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the remove() method. It's removes child elements matching a selection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = $('ul li').html().remove('ul');
    alert(elem);
});
```